# Pinch to zoom camera

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, zooming

I'm trying to make a pinch to zoom camera but I'm encountering two problems. First is that it allows the user to zoom way too much in and way to much out, secondly when I take a picture it doesn't take it of the zoomed in view. Here is my code for the pinch function...

```
func pinch(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = cameraView {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform,
            pinch.scale, pinch.scale)
            pinch.scale = 1
    }

}
```

Tell me if you need to see any more code. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have experienced the same issues with the camera implementation. To solve this you need to know about two things.

- The max and min zoom has to be within a value or else it results in the camera zooming in way too much.
- As with the actual image not saving the zoomed in image, it is a common bug a lot of solutions online do not cover. This is actually because you are only changing the view's zoom and not the actual `AVCaptureDevice`'s zoom.

To change the two things you need something like this:

```
func pinch(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
   var device: AVCaptureDevice = self.videoDevice
   var vZoomFactor = ((gestureRecognizer as! UIPinchGestureRecognizer).scale)
   var error:NSError!
        do{
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer {device.unlockForConfiguration()}
            if (vZoomFactor <= device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor){
                device.videoZoomFactor = vZoomFactor
            }else{
            NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: (max %f, asked %f)", device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor, vZoomFactor);
            }
        }catch error as NSError{
             NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }catch _{

        }
}
```

As you can see I use a class variable for the video device (`videoDevice`) to keep track of the capture device I am using for visual component. I restrict the zoom to a particular range and change the zoom property on the device and not the view itself!

Comment: There's one thing missing. You have to track the current zoom factor and use it in the calculations for the zoom factor that should be set. But thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Hi, Your answer was crashing for me when i try to zoom out. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 52):

#### Swift 3.0 || 4.0

1. Define zoom levels.

```
let minimumZoom: CGFloat = 1.0
let maximumZoom: CGFloat = 3.0
var lastZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
```

2. Add Pinch Gesture on CameraView.

```
let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pinch(_:)))        
            self.viewCamera.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)
```

3. Pinch-action method with the logic of `zoomin` and `zoom out`

```
func pinch(_ pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let device = videoDeviceInput.device else { return }

        // Return zoom value between the minimum and maximum zoom values
        func minMaxZoom(_ factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            return min(min(max(factor, minimumZoom), maximumZoom), device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)
        }

        func update(scale factor: CGFloat) {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
                defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
                device.videoZoomFactor = factor
            } catch {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        let newScaleFactor = minMaxZoom(pinch.scale * lastZoomFactor)

        switch pinch.state {
        case .began: fallthrough
        case .changed: update(scale: newScaleFactor)
        case .ended:
            lastZoomFactor = minMaxZoom(newScaleFactor)
            update(scale: lastZoomFactor)
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Thanks. Happy coding

Comment: Great and well-written answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thx nice example.

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid saving `prevZoomFactor` by simply resetting `UIPinchGestureRecognizer.scale` to 1 like this:

```swift
    @IBAction func pinchAction(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let device = currentCaptureDevice else {return}
        var zoom = device.videoZoomFactor * sender.scale
        sender.scale = 1.0
        var error:NSError!
        do{
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            defer {device.unlockForConfiguration()}
            if zoom >= device.minAvailableVideoZoomFactor && zoom <= device.maxAvailableVideoZoomFactor {
                device.videoZoomFactor = zoom
            }else{
                NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: (max %f, asked %f)", device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor, zoom);
            }
        }catch error as NSError{
            NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }catch _{
        }
    }
```

This was recommended by Apple at a WWDC event I attended way back when gesture recognizers first came out.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a manual zoomTo(2.0) function, you can use this

```
// Create listener for Pinch to Zoom
let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(FSCameraView.pinchToZoom(_:)))
pinchRecognizer.delegate = self
self.previewViewContainer.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)

// set the zoom to a zoomed in mode from start
setZoom(CGFloat(2.0)



// and the functions
func pinchToZoom(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    var vZoomFactor = ((sender as! UIPinchGestureRecognizer).scale)
    setZoom(vZoomFactor)
}

func setZoom(zoomFactor:CGFloat) {
    var device: AVCaptureDevice = self.device!
    var error:NSError!
    do{
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        defer {device.unlockForConfiguration()}
        if (zoomFactor <= device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor) {

            let desiredZoomFactor:CGFloat = zoomFactor + atan2(sender.velocity, 5.0);
            device.videoZoomFactor = max(1.0, min(desiredZoomFactor, device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor));
        }
        else {
            NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: (max %f, asked %f)", device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        }
    }
    catch error as NSError{
        NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    catch _{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var device: AVCaptureDevice = self.backCamera
    var vZoomFactor = sender.scale
    var error:NSError!
    do{
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        defer {device.unlockForConfiguration()}
        if (vZoomFactor <= device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor) {

            let desiredZoomFactor:CGFloat = vZoomFactor + atan2(sender.velocity, 5.0);
            device.videoZoomFactor = max(1.0, min(desiredZoomFactor, device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor));
        }
        else {

            NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: (max %f, asked %f)", device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor, vZoomFactor);
        }
    }
    catch error as NSError{

        NSLog("Unable to set videoZoom: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    catch _{

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on **Ritvik Upadhyaya's** answer, you would also need to save the previous zoom factor to calculate the new one, you wouldn't want the zooming to reset to normal every time you lift up your fingers and try zooming again.

```
// To track the zoom factor
var prevZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1

func pinch(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    var device: AVCaptureDevice = self.videoDevice

    // Here we multiply vZoomFactor with the previous zoom factor if it exist. 
    // Else just multiply by 1
    var vZoomFactor = pinch.scale * prevZoomFactor

    // If the pinching has ended, update prevZoomFactor.
    // Note that we set the limit at 1, because zoom factor cannot be less than 1 or the setting device.videoZoomFactor will crash
    if sender.state == .ended {
        prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor >= 1 ? zoomFactor : 1
    }

    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        defer {device.unlockForConfiguration()}
        if (vZoomFactor <= device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor) {
            device.videoZoomFactor = vZoomFactor
        } else {
            print("Unable to set videoZoom: (max \(device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor), asked \(vZoomFactor))")
      }
    } catch {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello.  Wouldn't the app crash if vZoomFactor is smaller than 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.0 or above

***1. Define variable declaration and outlets.***

```
//#MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var camPreview: UIView!

let minimumZoom: CGFloat = 1.0
let maximumZoom: CGFloat = 2.0
var lastZoomFactor: CGFloat = 1.0
var newCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
```

***2. Get camera position and pinch gesture on Camera View.***

```
//#MARK: - Views methods    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    newCamera = cameraWithPosition(position: .back)  
    //Add Pinch Gesture on CameraView.
      let pinchRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pinch(_:)))
       self.camPreview.addGestureRecognizer(pinchRecognizer)
  }

// Find a camera with the specified AVCaptureDevicePosition, returning nil if one is not found

  func cameraWithPosition(position: AVCaptureDevice.Position) -> AVCaptureDevice? {
      let discoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
      for device in discoverySession.devices {
            if device.position == position {
                return device
            }
       }
       return nil
  }
```

**3. Pinch-action with zoom-in and zoom out functionality.**

```
  @objc func pinch(_ pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
          guard let device = newCamera else { return }
    
          // Return zoom value between the minimum and maximum zoom values
          func minMaxZoom(_ factor: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
                return min(min(max(factor, minimumZoom), maximumZoom), device.activeFormat.videoMaxZoomFactor)
          }
    
          func update(scale factor: CGFloat) {
               do {
                     try device.lockForConfiguration()
                     defer { device.unlockForConfiguration() }
                     device.videoZoomFactor = factor
                  } catch {
                     print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                  }
          }
    
          let newScaleFactor = minMaxZoom(pinch.scale * lastZoomFactor)
    
          switch pinch.state {
                case .began: fallthrough
                case .changed: update(scale: newScaleFactor)
                case .ended:
                    lastZoomFactor = minMaxZoom(newScaleFactor)
                    update(scale: lastZoomFactor)
                default: break
                }
           }
  }
```